# Internal Server Error 500 when using Web Api Http Put

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm developing a Webapp to a company that use Picking Process.

The process is very simple, I have a sales order with some information, and i creating a picking list with some of that information (for example: number of items, total weight, and id of sales order).

I'm getting always this error

> Internal Server Error

...when I'm trying to use PUT method, to create a Picking List and add it into a database in Web Api side.

When I remove `[HttpPost]` the error change to :

> Method Not Found

or

> Method Not Allowed

This is my code:

**Client Side**

```
public async Task<bool> AddTarefa(ListasPicking listaPickingAdd) 
{
    String listaparaAdicionar = listaPickingAdd.idLista + ";" + listaPickingAdd.IDordemVenda + ";" + listaPickingAdd.peso + ";" + listaPickingAdd.itens;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await cliente.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ListasPicking/", listaparaAdicionar);

    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

**Web Api Side - Controllers**

```
//PUT: api/ListasPicking
[ResponseType(typeof (ListasPicking))]
[HttpPut]
public  IHttpActionResult PutLista ([FromBody] String lista)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    String[] result = lista.Split(';');
    ListasPicking novaLista = new ListasPicking();
    novaLista.idLista=result[0];
    novaLista.IDordemVenda = result[1];
    string lista_peso_converttoDouble = result[2];
    novaLista.peso = Convert.ToDouble(lista_peso_converttoDouble);
    string lista_items_converttoInt = result[3];
    novaLista.itens = Convert.ToInt32(lista_items_converttoInt);

    primContext.ListasPickingGet.Add(novaLista);
    primContext.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

I trying some solutions related to this kind of problem, and the same error (s).

**Web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="PrimaveraRest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <!--    <remove name="WebDAV"/> -->

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>

     <!-- <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> -->
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>


  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <applicationSettings>
    <PrimaveraRest.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Company" serializeAs="String">
        <value>DEMO</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="User" serializeAs="String">
        <value>adminfixe</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
        <value>123456</value>
      </setting>
    </PrimaveraRest.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE**

When I rebuild my solution, i'm getting some lines like this:

> Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5):
>   warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor
>   architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor
>   architecture of the reference "Interop.ICrmDS800", "x86". This
>   mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project

Can be the problem? Interop.dll is a file that i include in my project to use a external program to get the information about sales order.

**SOLUTION**

The [Key] annotation is missing in "ListaPicking" Model, and i was passing a DateTime variable with default value... I just change to for example DateTime.Today and now it's working :)

Comment: Check the result.Length before trying to access to it's members. Also it would be better if you debug your code and add exception of the server side to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just send the entire model

```
public async Task<bool> AddTarefa(ListasPicking listaPickingAdd) {

    var response = await cliente.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ListasPicking/", listaPickingAdd);

    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;        
}
```

And receive it at the action the same way instead of deconstructing and reconstructing it.

```
[ResponseType(typeof (ListasPicking))]
[HttpPut]
public  IHttpActionResult PutLista ([FromBody] ListasPicking novaLista) {
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    primContext.ListasPickingGet.Add(novaLista);
    primContext.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting the error...  see my update please!

Comment: @bullprog follow the clearly stated instructions provided in the error message

Comment: the warning disappear, but i'm getting the same error "internal server error". Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @bullprog you need to narrow down exactly where the error is occurring. Is it calling the action or is the error happening before it gets to the action? If it is reaching the action then put a try catch in there just to see if the error is being thrown when trying to save the record. That could probably give you more information as to what is causing the error.

Comment: @bullprog well at least you have narrowed down where the error is being thrown. What is the error. It has to be related to your data store (Entity Framework)

Comment: it's working! Missing the param [Key] and DateTime that i was passing is default, so i have to put today datetime and now it's working thanks for help! :)

Comment: @bullprog glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You call `PutAsJsonAsync` but then you pass a non json string as your data parameter when it expects a string that represents json.

From the documentation:

> Sends a PUT request as an asynchronous operation to the specified Uri with the given value serialized as JSON.

To make it work call `PutAsync` instead.

Comment: now tell that string cannot be convert to http.content.

Comment: @bullprog - you should be able to set the `content-type` in the header, use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and prefix the string value with `=`. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138124(v=vs.118).aspx).